# How does work the signature appearance in Itext 7?

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

Has anybody already played with the signature appearance of PdfSignatureFormField in Itext 7 ? If yes, could you please give a little explanation and/or a little example

Thanks in advance

David L.

Answer (score 1):

You have itext7 samples here:
http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples/tree/develop

This is a sample about signature with appearance:
http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples/blob/develop/publications/signatures/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/signatures/chapter03/C3_01_SignWithCAcert.java